# How to use Qt Creator with Python?

Tags: application-development, python, qt, qt-creator, qml

I want to use Qt for developing Ubuntu desktop, phone and tablet applications but I don't want to learn a new programming language (C++, JavaScript). Is it possible to write Qt application in Python utilizing Qt-Creator as IDE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Qt-Creator is a C++ IDE, with little support for other languages but since version 2.8.0 a quite basic python support has been added.

That said you can use Qt-Designer (the form building tool), Qt-Translator (the translate tool), etc... easily with python.

There are two Qt-Python bindings right now, the GPL/Commercial dual licensed [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro), and the LGPL [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category%3aLanguageBindings%3a%3aPySide). I have used PyQt for a long time and I'm a happy user, I also have tried PySide but it looks less mature to me. If your license requirements allow you I'd go for PyQt.

Comment: recently added https://codereview.qt-project.org/#q,status:open,n,z

Answer (score 18):

Just desing your interface in Qt-Designer and convert it to python file executing **pyuic4**.

Eg:

```
pyuic4 editorFrame.ui -o editorFrame.py
```

then you can import it from your main class, in this case i'm using a QMainWindow:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from editorFrame import Ui_MainWindow

class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Editor, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Editor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just in case someone need this info, to install pyuic4: `sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools qt4-designer`

Answer (score 8):

With the release of Qt Creator 2.8 things are changing. It now natively supports Python for code editing and there are few Python-based features.

From [Qt Creator 2.8 release announcement](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/07/11/qt-creator-2-8-0-released/):

> An editor specific for Python was added, with highlighting and indentation, and a Python class wizard

Answer (score 2):

You may want to follow this tutorial series though : [Developing Cross Platform Application using Qt, PyQt and PySide : GUI Application Development - Part 5 of 5](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1zb0s1/a_complete_hands_on_gui_development_using_either/). It completely discuss Qt dev using C++, PyQt and PySide

Comment: The link of the tutorial is not valid any more.